# Android getting error : Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask')

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Getting Below error in running Android App-

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
}
```

Added above dependencies as well.

Gradle version - 7.6

Corodva 11

tried different versions no luck

```
**Error** -
    
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException: Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageName' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageName'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageName'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'moduleGroup' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'moduleGroup'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'moduleGroup'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'moduleGroupFirebase' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'moduleGroupFirebase'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'moduleGroupFirebase'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
at org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException$BuilderWithSummary.build(WorkValidationException.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException$BuilderWithSummary.get(WorkValidationException.java:115)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultNodeValidator.reportErrors(DefaultNodeValidator.java:83)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultNodeValidator.hasValidationProblems(DefaultNodeValidator.java:45)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.ResolveMutationsNode.doResolveMutations(ResolveMutationsNode.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.ResolveMutationsNode.access$000(ResolveMutationsNode.java:31)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.ResolveMutationsNode$1.run(ResolveMutationsNode.java:87)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.ResolveMutationsNode.execute(ResolveMutationsNode.java:83)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.WorkNodeExecutor.execute(WorkNodeExecutor.java:27)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
```